# Java project does not compile after switching from Maven to Gradle with "cannot find symbol" errors

Tags: java, maven, gradle, compiler-errors, compilation

I had a Maven project, which I then switched to Gradle. I am now attempting to compile the Gradle project, but it isn't compiling, even if it was building and compiling successfully when I used Maven.

I ran `gradle init` to convert my project to Gradle and it stopped compiling and gave me the "cannot find symbol" errors. It seems as though Gradle cannot find many classes, including the `Main` class.

I have effectively read through the post: [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean) and I was unable to fix my issue. I know it's a compilation error, but I don't know what's causing it. I didn't change the code when I switched from Maven to Gradle, only the build files.

Here is an example of one of the errors:

```
        Main instance = Main.getInstance();
                            ^
  symbol:   method getInstance()
  location: class Main
```

Note: the build is a multi-project build. It has several subprojects. Here is the mother build.gradle file:

```clj
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
    id "war"
}

group "net.pixlies"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

subprojects {
    compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = 17
        targetCompatibility = 17
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.purpurmc.org/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.dmulloy2.net/repository/public/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.11"
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0"
    implementation "co.aikar:acf-paper:0.5.1-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:5.0.3.Final"
    implementation "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6"
}
```

Here is the settings.gradle file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/" }
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'version-two'

include(':PixliesCore')
include(':LobbyModule')
include(':MiniMick')
include(':ProtoBusiness')
include(':PixliesFun')
include(':Nations')
include(':DiploMaurice')
include(':PixliesProxyCore')
```

The PixliesCore project is having these issues with the "Cannot find symbol" error. Here is the `PixliesCore` subproject build.gradle file:

```clj
plugins {
    id 'net.pixlies.java-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework:IF:0.10.7'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:4.2.3'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.11.1'
    compileOnly 'org.purpurmc.purpur:purpur-api:1.19-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly 'com.comphenix.protocol:ProtocolLib:4.7.0'
    compileOnly 'me.clip:placeholderapi:2.11.2'
    compileOnly 'net.luckperms:api:5.4'
}

description = 'PixliesCore'
```

I also ran `./gradlew assemble` in the mother project's directory. Here is the output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':PixliesCore:compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 17
```

Perhaps this "invalid source release" is the cause, but I do not know what it means or how to fix it. I'm using the Java 17 SDK for everything.

Oh, also, here is the original POM.xml for the mother project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <modules>
        <module>PixliesCore</module>
        <module>Nations</module>
        <module>MiniMick</module>
        <module>LobbyModule</module>
        <module>PixliesFun</module>
        <module>PixliesProxyCore</module>
        <module>DiploMaurice</module>
        <module>ProtoBusiness</module>
    </modules>

    <groupId>net.pixlies</groupId>
    <artifactId>version-two</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.aikar</groupId>
            <artifactId>acf-paper</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>purpur</id>
            <url>https://repo.purpurmc.org/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>aikar</id>
            <url>https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/</url>
        </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>placeholderapi</id>
                <url>https://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/</url>
            </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.dmulloy2.net/repository/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the POM.xml for the `PixliesCore` subproject:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>version-two</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.pixlies</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>PixliesCore</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>aikar</id>
            <url>https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>IF</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.purpurmc.purpur</groupId>
            <artifactId>purpur-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.19-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.comphenix.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProtocolLib</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.clip</groupId>
            <artifactId>placeholderapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.luckperms</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>PixliesCore</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dependencyReducedPomLocation>${project.build.directory}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is the `Main` class and does it have a `getInstance()` method?

Comment: The Main class contains the `getInstance()` method because it uses a singleton pattern.

Comment: What does the original `pom.xml` have?

Comment: Which module or dependency is `Main` in?

Comment: It's in the `PixliesCore` subproject.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320448/spring-boot-gradle-build-invalid-source-release-11

Comment: That cleared up the "invalid source release," thanks. However, the "cannot find symbol" issue is still persisting.